# Objective C - Swift compatibility / How could i add/modify variable in Objective C from a Swift class

Tags: objective-c, swift, global-variables

Need your precious help on a compatibility between Objective C and Swift. I'm a Swift guy so complicated for me with Objective c.

I have a class in Objective C displaying an static Image. I want to set a variable instead of a static name and modify the image from a Swift.class.

Here's the `"GSKSpotyLikeHeaderView.m"`

```
#import "GSKSpotyLikeHeaderView.h"
@interface GSKSpotyLikeHeaderView ()

@property (nonatomic) UIImageView *backgroundImageView;

@end

@implementation GSKSpotyLikeHeaderView

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.minimumContentHeight = 64;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.2 alpha:1];
        [self setupViews];
        [self setupViewConstraints];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setupViews {
    self.backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageprincipalelachaise"]];
    self.backgroundImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    self.backgroundImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.backgroundImageView]
}
```

Here's my Swift class

```
import GSKStretchyHeaderView
class PresentationViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate,SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKRequestDelegate{


  //i ve tried with the Getter/Setter but without success.

    var backgroundImage: UIImage? {
        get { return self.backgroundImageView.image }
        set { self.backgroundImageView.image = newValue }
    }

 var stretchyHeader: GSKSpotyLikeHeaderView!


        let headerSize = CGSize(width: self.mainscrollView.frame.size.width,
                                height: 200) 
        self.stretchyHeader = GSKSpotyLikeHeaderView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: headerSize.width, height: headerSize.height))

        self.mainscrollView.addSubview(self.stretchyHeader)
```

With my Getter/Setter , i ve got : `Value of type 'PresentationViewController' has no member 'backgroundImageView'`

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Did you not mean to use `self.stretchyHeader.backgroundImageView`?

Comment: When i add it like that :  `get { return self.stretchyHeader.backgroundImageView.image }` I et the following error message : `Value of type 'GSKSpotyLikeHeaderView' has no member 'backgroundImageView'`

Comment: It looks like you have declared the property in a *class extension* in the implementation file (`.m`) instead of in the *class interface* in the public header file (`.h`), so Swift will not see it. You should read up on the Obj-C interface/implementation class model which is a little different to the Swift class model.